# UWP: Can't enter a number to masked TextBox using Touch screen numeric pad

Tags: c#, xaml, maskedtextbox

I designed a masked `TextBox` on my project to enter time-format numbers (using colons like `00:00:00`) and it works well with a physical keyboard but unfortunately not with the numeric keypad of a touchscreen!

Does anybody have any suggestions how solve this?

This is the XAML code:

```
<Page
x:Class="test.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:test"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-    compatibility/2006"
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
mc:Ignorable="d" Width="800" Height="480">

   <Grid Background="{ThemeResource     ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBox
        controls:TextBoxMask.CustomMask="5:[0-5]"
        controls:TextBoxMask.Mask="5:59:59"
        Name="Textbox"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Width="200" Margin="442,166,158,282"/>
    <Button x:Name="button11" Content="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"    Margin="130,122,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="45" Height="45" Foreground="#FFA8A8A8" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" BorderThickness="1" ClickMode="Press" BorderBrush="#FFC9C9C9" Tapped="button11_Tapped">
        <Button.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFE6E6E6" Offset="0.47"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="button12" Content="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left"    Margin="186,122,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="45" Height="45" Foreground="#FFA8A8A8" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" BorderThickness="1" ClickMode="Press" BorderBrush="#FFC9C9C9">
        <Button.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFE6E6E6" Offset="0.47"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="button13" Content="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="242,122,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="45" Height="45" Foreground="#FFA8A8A8" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" BorderThickness="1" ClickMode="Press" BorderBrush="#FFC9C9C9">
        <Button.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFE6E6E6" Offset="0.47"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="button14" Content="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,178,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="45" Height="45" Foreground="#FFA8A8A8" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" BorderThickness="1" ClickMode="Press" BorderBrush="#FFC9C9C9">
        <Button.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFE6E6E6" Offset="0.47"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="button15" Content="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="186,178,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="45" Height="45" Foreground="#FFA8A8A8" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" BorderThickness="1" ClickMode="Press" BorderBrush="#FFC9C9C9" Tapped="button11_Tapped">
        <Button.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFE6E6E6" Offset="0.47"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="button16" Content="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="242,178,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="45" Height="45" Foreground="#FFA8A8A8" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" BorderThickness="1" ClickMode="Press" BorderBrush="#FFC9C9C9">
        <Button.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFE6E6E6" Offset="0.47"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="button17" Content="7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,234,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="45" Height="45" Foreground="#FFA8A8A8" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" BorderThickness="1" ClickMode="Press" BorderBrush="#FFC9C9C9">
        <Button.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFE6E6E6" Offset="0.47"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="button18" Content="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="186,234,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="45" Height="45" Foreground="#FFA8A8A8" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" BorderThickness="1" ClickMode="Press" BorderBrush="#FFC9C9C9">
        <Button.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFE6E6E6" Offset="0.47"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="button19" Content="9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="242,234,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="45" Height="45" Foreground="#FFA8A8A8" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" BorderThickness="1" ClickMode="Press" BorderBrush="#FFC9C9C9">
        <Button.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFE6E6E6" Offset="0.47"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="button20" Content="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="186,290,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="45" Height="45" Foreground="#FFA8A8A8" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" BorderThickness="1" ClickMode="Press" BorderBrush="#FFC9C9C9">
        <Button.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFE6E6E6" Offset="0.47"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="button_delete11" Content="&#xE94F;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="242,290,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="45" Height="45" Foreground="#FFA8A8A8" FontSize="16" BorderThickness="1" ClickMode="Press" BorderBrush="#FFC9C9C9" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets">
        <Button.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFE6E6E6" Offset="0.47"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="button_accept11" Content="&#xEC61;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="298,122,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="45" Height="213" Foreground="White" FontSize="20" BorderThickness="0" ClickMode="Press" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontWeight="Bold">
        <Button.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF6CC98A" Offset="1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFA2FFC1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="button_cancel11" Content="&#xEB90;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,290,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="45" Height="45" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" ClickMode="Press" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets">
        <Button.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF75959" Offset="1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFF9E9E"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <TextBox
        x:Name="Textbox_Copy"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Width="200" Margin="442,274,158,174"/>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

And this is the code behind :

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button11_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button Btn = (Button)sender;
        Textbox_Copy.Text = Textbox_Copy.Text + Btn.Content;
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed the title, some code formatting and some grammar.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue before. This issue occurred due to some events get handled. Check whether any events get handled when touching on the text box that you designen using any tools like xaml spy

Comment: I build another project which has simply one textbox (Masked) and some sets of numeric keys and get rid of excess event handlers , but so far nothing good :(